# html5 canvas and emberjs view

Tags: ember.js

I'd like to add some drawing functionality in my ember based application. I plan to use the html5 canvas element. Basically, in my DOM I have

```
<canvas id="my-canvas">
```

And I need to get my canvas context when the DOM is loaded with

```
var c = document.getElementById('my-canvas')
// ... do something with c
```

If the canvas is represented with an Ember.View :

```
App.Canvas = Em.View.extend({
 tagName: 'canvas'
})
```

What is the equivalent of `document.getElementById`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var view = App.Canvas.create().append();
var viewContext = Ember.get(view, 'element');
```

`viewContext` will hold what you need.

Comment: Thanks @roy-daniels.  In case anyone is wondering, the `element` property is accessible from within an `Ember.View.extend({...})` declaration.  This is particularly handy with an element like canvas because you can access the entire canvas API from within your special-purpose view.

Answer (score 1):

From the canvas context, you could use the $() method:

```
this.$('#id')
```

which provides a JQuery-flavored way to access elements.