# Ember.js - TypeError: DynamicCanvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: ember.js

How can I get the context of the canvas element? This line

```
DynamicContext = DynamicCanvas.getContext("2d"); // ERROR
```

throws this error:

```
TypeError: DynamicCanvas.getContext is not a function   
         DynamicContext = DynamicCanvas.getContext("2d");
```

**Source Code**

Html

```
script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view "App.Canvas"}}   
</script>
```

Ember.js

```
App.Canvas = Em.View.extend({
    //attrs for canvas element
    tagName: "canvas",
    attributeBindings: ['height', 'width'],
    height: 300,
    width: 300,
    faceRadius: 40,

    didInsertElement: function(){

        this.drawStaticCanvas();
        this.drawDynamicCanvas();
    },

    drawDynamicCanvas: function(){      
    // How to get the context?


    DynamicContext = DynamicCanvas.getContext("2d"); // ERROR

    // face 
    DynamicContext.beginPath();
    DynamicContext.arc(300/2, // x x,y is at the center
        300/2, // y
        100, // arc radius
        0, // starting angle
        (360 * Math.PI)/180, // ending angle
        true); // counter-clockwise
    DynamicContext.fillStyle = "#ffddee";
    DynamicContext.fill();
    DynamicContext.stroke();    
    }
});
```

Comment: This cannot work, because you are just reading the tagName from your view object. And this is set to the string "canvas". There is no object.

Comment: @mavilein: How can I fix my source, in order to get the object and afterward the context?

Comment: From this snippet, no one can tell. What is DynamicCanvas? One sees you are trying to invoke methods, but nowhere the object gets created. I suppose you know little of javascript. Where do you have this snippet from?

Comment: The DOM node is accesible via the `element` property. Also, why are you creating an instance of App.Canvas inside an already instantiated copy of App.Canvas? You just want to use `this` to access the view.

Comment: @mavilein: [code snipped link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9890709/htlm5-canvas-and-emberjs-view)

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey: agreed, that makes no sense.

Comment: I added a jsFiddle: [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/dTyf7/3/). Sorry, that's not style and context conform, but that's my status quo.

Comment: Fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/dTyf7/4/

Comment: @ChristopherSwasey: you safed my day! Thanks~